Selectively apply implicit/.animation-modifier-based animations
Given the following example that uses explicit animations (withAnimation) to change the size of a rect (animated) and its color (not animated):
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var size: CGFloat = 200
    @State var color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.size = self.size == 200 ? 300 : 200
                }
                self.color = self.color == .red ? .blue : .red
            }
        }
    }
}

I want to get the same result from a single state property using an implicit animation/using the .animation modifier. (Why? Sometimes it's handy to have fine-grained control over animations without having to wrap all the places where the underlying state changes, also it's an example to deepen my understanding of the SwiftUI animation APIs).
.animate() with value
As a starting point, let's keep the two separate state properties and try to animate it using .animation with a value:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var size: CGFloat = 200
    @State var color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .animation(.linear, value: self.size)  // <---
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.size = self.size == 200 ? 300 : 200
                self.color = self.color == .red ? .blue : .red
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Surprisingly, this does animate both changes (tested on iOS 17.4).
When using just a single state property, from my understanding, one should be able to get the effect using two .animation modifiers with a value (there is even an example in the tutorial from Apple for this style here):
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var value = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(self.value ? .red : .blue)
                .animation(nil, value: self.value) // <--
                .frame(width: self.value ? 300 : 200, height: self.value ? 300 : 200)
                .animation(.linear, value: self.value) // <--
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.value.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

Surprisingly, no animation at all. What's going on here and is there a way to get this effect using .animation(value:) on iOS 16?
.animate() with view-closure
I thought that's what the new .animation with a view-closure that was introduced in iOS 17 is for:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var value = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(self.value ? .red : .blue)
                .animation(.linear) { content in
                    content.frame(width: self.value ? 300 : 200, height: self.value ? 300 : 200)
                }
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.value.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

Surprisingly, also no animation at all. Why is that and how can one get this effect using implicit animations?

As you found out in your answer, frame is not "animatable". Looking at the SwiftUI headers, we can see that frame applies a _FrameLayout modifier.
 @frozen public struct _FrameLayout {
     internal let width: CoreFoundation.CGFloat?
     internal let height: CoreFoundation.CGFloat?
     internal let alignment: SwiftUI.Alignment
     @usableFromInline
     internal init(width: CoreFoundation.CGFloat?, height: CoreFoundation.CGFloat?, alignment: SwiftUI.Alignment)
     public typealias AnimatableData = SwiftUI.EmptyAnimatableData
     public typealias Body = Swift.Never
 }
 
 extension SwiftUI.View {
     @inlinable public func frame(width: CoreFoundation.CGFloat? = nil, height: CoreFoundation.CGFloat? = nil, alignment: SwiftUI.Alignment = .center) -> some SwiftUI.View {
         return modifier(
            _FrameLayout(width: width, height: height, alignment: alignment))
     }
 }

You can find this in the .swiftinterface files in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Modules/SwiftUI.swiftmodule
_FrameLayout conforms to Animatable, but its animatableData is EmptyAnimatableData, so nothing gets animated.
You can create your own Animatable view modifier with the width and height as animatable data.
struct AnimatableFrame: ViewModifier, Animatable {
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
        get { .init(width, height) }
        set {
            width = newValue.first
            height = newValue.second
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}

extension View {
    func animatableFrame(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) -> some View {
        modifier(AnimatableFrame(width: width, height: height))
    }
}

Now the frame animates as you would expect.
Compare this with the view modifier used by scaleEffect, which uses a CGSize (the scale) and a UnitPoint (the anchor) as its animatableData.
@frozen public struct _ScaleEffect : SwiftUI.GeometryEffect, Swift.Equatable {

  ...

  public typealias AnimatableData = SwiftUI.AnimatablePair<CoreFoundation.CGSize.AnimatableData, SwiftUI.UnitPoint.AnimatableData>
  public var animatableData: SwiftUI._ScaleEffect.AnimatableData {
    get
    set
  }

  ...
}


.frame animates normally when you are setting size, because the type of size, CGFloat, is Animatable. On the other hand, Bool is not Animatable.
Both .frame and .fill animates even when you only wrote .animation(.linear, value: self.size), because you set size and color "at the same time". By the time SwiftUI compares the view to see what to animate, both size and color has been changed to the new value, so both of them animate. If you delay setting color using DispatchQueue.main.async for example, only frame animates.
Note that the meaning of .animation(.linear, value: self.size) doesn't mean "animate self.size", but "animate when self.size changes". Everything animatable that changed, animates, not just self.size.

It seems, .frame is special somehow. I thought it's a regular animatable property because it worked using withAnimation. Everything works as expected if I use scaleFactor instead:
iOS 17:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var value = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(self.value ? .red : .blue)
                .animation(.linear) { content in   // <---
                    content.scaleEffect(self.value ? 1.5 : 1.0)
                }
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            Button("Toggle") {
                self.value.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}


iOS 16:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var value = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(self.value ? .red : .blue)
                .animation(nil, value: self.value) // <--
                .scaleEffect(self.value ? 1.5 : 1.0)
                .animation(.linear, value: self.value) // <--
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            Button("Toggle") {
                self.value.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

It seems there are properties that work well with selective implicit animations like .opacity, .cornerRadius, .scaleEffect. But for example, for .frame, .offset, .padding, .foregroundColor it does not work. Also see here: When .animation animates more (or less) than it’s supposed to
I think it's also notable that it's not enough to restrict the change by the value passed to .animation, this will animate size and color:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var size: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
                .scaleEffect(size)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .animation(.linear, value: self.size)  // <---

            Button("Toggle") {
                self.size = self.size == 1.0 ? 1.5 : 1.0
                self.color = self.color == .red ? .blue : .red
            }
        }
    }
}

